# How to use angular directive scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my razor view I have a table as follows:

```
<form>
    <table class="table">
        <thead><tr>
                   <th>Artist Name</th>
                   <th>Track Title</th>
                   <th>Version</th>
                   <th>Track Duration</th>
                   <th>Recording Year(20xx)</th>
                   <th></th>
               </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr isrcrow> </tr>

       </tbody>
```

And here is the directive for "isrcrow"

```
isrcorderapp.directive "isrcrow", () ->
    restrict:'A'
    template: '<td><input id="artist" ng-model="artist"/></td>
                <td><input id="title" ng-model="title"/></td>
                <td><select id="isrctype" ng-model="isrctype" ng-change="setState(state)" ng-options="s.type for s in recordingTypes" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"></select></td>
                <td><input id="duration"/></td>
                <td><input id="year"/></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Add ISRC" onclick="AddIsrc()" class="btn btn-small btn-success" />
                    <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="RemoveIsrc()" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" />
                </td>'
    replace: false
    scope:
        name:'='
        ng-options=''

    link: (scope,element,attr) ->

isrcorderapp.controller "isrcorders", ($scope,$http) ->
    $scope.recordingTypes = [
        {type:'A'}
        {type:'B'}
        {type:'C'}
        {type:'D'}
        {type:'E'}
        ]
```

When the table is rendered it doesnt populate the select list.

The problem may be the scope properties.

How should this part of the template be refered in the scope:
ng-options="s.type for s in recordingTypes" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"

I am not clear on when to use = or @

Comment: You aren't assigning the controller to the directive, for starters.  controller: 'isrcorders'

Comment: Your scope properties in your directive don't appear to be doing anything right now (the ng-options declaration is malformed).  I don't see where you need them at all for this, did I miss something?

Comment: I am new to angular .how would I do that

Comment: Just add controller: 'isrcorders' into your directive.  For example, right between restrict: 'A' and template:.

Comment: ng-options="s.type for s in recordingTypes =  $scope.recordingTypes

Comment: I'm saying this whole "scope:" piece in your directive is not necessary.  The "name and "ng-options" here would get assigned if you put those attributes on your directive's element in the template.

Comment: I removed the scope and put the  scope.recordingTypes  right after restrict:'A' and before template:  and that didnt work

Comment: Can you make a plunker or jsfiddle, please?  Then I can just change it directly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6K6mz/

Comment: Here, I made this from your original code.  http://plnkr.co/edit/smL8FX6hmUAqSrXjOlSj?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put your original code into a plunker.  The controller was not being specified on the directive (unless it is somewhere higher in your DOM?).  The isolate scope in the directive is not necessary, as far as I can tell, and can be removed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/smL8FX6hmUAqSrXjOlSj?p=preview

```
<tbody>
    <tr isrcrow> </tr>
</tbody>

var isrcorderapp = angular.module('plunker', []);

isrcorderapp.directive("isrcrow", function(){
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    controller: 'isrcorders',
    template: '<td><input id="artist" ng-model="artist"/></td>\
                <td><input id="title" ng-model="title"/></td>\
                <td><select id="isrctype" ng-model="isrctype" ng-change="setState(state)" ng-options="s.type for s in recordingTypes" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"></select></td>\
                <td><input id="duration"/></td>\
                <td><input id="year"/></td>\
                <td><input type="button" value="Add ISRC" onclick="AddIsrc()" class="btn btn-small btn-success" />\
                    <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="RemoveIsrc()" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" />\
                </td>',
    replace: false
  }
});

isrcorderapp.controller("isrcorders", function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.recordingTypes = [
        {type:'A'},
        {type:'B'},
        {type:'C'},
        {type:'D'},
        {type:'E'}
        ];
});
```